# Can I use Websphere application server V8.0.0.10 (network deployment) for mobilefirst 7.1 clustering?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-8, mobilefirst-server

I have done Websphere application server V8.5 (network deployment) clustering for mobilefirst 7.1 using this link.

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/t_setting_up_WL_WAS_ND_8_cluster_env.html

Everything is working fine.
But for this I used WAS ND V8.5.

Is similar clustering possible with WAD ND V8.0.0.10? I know that mobilefirst 7.1 is compatible with WAS ND V8.0.0.10 but not sure about clustering.

Can't find it any of document related this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support is available from WAS ND 8.0.0.**10** onwards.
You cannot use WAS ND 8.0.0.3.

See here: http://www-969.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/softwareReqsForProduct?deliverableId=46183B706BEA11E48038141DE954FC88&osPlatforms=AIX%7CLinux%7CMac%20OS%7CMobile%20OS%7CSolaris%7CWindows&duComponentIds=S001#sw-0

Under "Supported Software -> Application Servers".

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my question. But for clustering, it will work fine?
As per link shared by me, *You can set up a MobileFirst cluster environment with IBM® WebSphere® Application Server Network Deployment V8.5 and IBM HTTP Server.*

Comment: Thanks for answer.